# why 'Generating DAG in progress' and 'Looking for peers' keep showing forever when I try to use geth to build up a private chain on my local computer?

Tags: console, blockchain, ethereum, directed-acyclic-graphs, geth

I just try to learn etherum, geth and so forth. Now i am doing:

```
feng@DESKTOP-PNE7LPV:~/myChain$ ../go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --datadir . --networkid 312 console
```

I use this way to start a private chain and open the console. It all looks fine. But there is a problem:

[image]

This kind of information keeps jumping forever. Could anyone tell me why this happens and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I have got it. build up a log file then all the updates will only show there.